# Convert byte of array data to pdf download?

Tags: php

[image]

Please see the added image and let me know if anyone have solution for to convert this byte array to pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a PDF file:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
$pdf_file = fopen( 'PDF_FILE_PATH', 'wb' );
```

Then you have to write byte array in PDF file:

```php
fwrite( $pdf_file, $byte_array); 
fclose( $pdf_file);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the byte stream and echo it

```
$byte_string="read the byte string";
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="service.pdf"');
echo base64_decode($byte_string);
```

Via: [Byte array to pdf file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995415/byte-array-to-pdf-file-in-php)

Comment: the data is not byte array

Comment: Actually i am implementing the Bluedart api for shipment and after creating the waybill generation its giving me the Array Of byte

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the `Content-Type` header first. Try this:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
$fp = fopen( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'filename.pdf', 'wb' ); 
fwrite( $fp, $print); 
fclose( $fp );
```